# Pipe to camera/image_raw

Tags: ros, image-pipeline

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a camera on a raspberry pi and am trying to stream the image in order to do the processing on a linux machine (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, ROS Indigo).
I'm currently streaming rawvideo from the pi using netcat through UDP and send that to a pipe file. Now I need to somehow make ROS get the image from the pipe (I guess either create some publisher that sends it to a topic or in some other way send the data to /camera/image_raw).
I also thought about doing a loopback from the pipe to a device with v4l2 and using rosusb, but seems like something that will add to the latency without much gain.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215490/pipe-to-camera/image_raw/) by [mihaibujanca](https://answers.ros.org/users/23511/mihaibujanca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this, but it should work.

What you could try is transmitting the stream via Gstreamer, running a Gstreamer pipeline on the Pi and another one on your target computer as input of the [gscam](http://wiki.ros.org/gscam) ROS camera driver.

[Here is a tutorial for using Gstreamer on the Pi](http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=150). What would need to be changed is piping the output to RGB output on the receiver side (instead of the video sink visualizer). This then can be used by the gscam driver which publishes standard ROS images.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0